# Calculate the probability of the drawn cards

Tags: probability

A box contains 7 identical cards numbered from 0 to 6 if two cards are drawn randomly without replacement 
Find the probability that :
$$a) $$ The two cards have even numbers
$$b)$$
The first card has an odd number and the second has an even number 
My turn :
Using the tree diagram i got
$$a) = \frac{12}{42}=\frac{2}{7}$$
$$b) = \frac{12}{42}= \frac{2}{7}$$
My question : Is there other solution using the conditional probability ?

Comment: Both answers are correct. Your question in the last statement is not very clear

Comment: If you did $\frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6}$ on the first problem, you have effectively used conditional probability since $\frac{3}{6}$ is the conditional probability of selecting a card with an even number on the second draw *given* that a card with an even number was selected on the first draw.

Comment: How did you calculate the conditional probability which is $$\frac{3}{6}$$ @N.F.Taussing

Answer (score 1):

No. Conditional probability doesn't help here; this really is just a straightforward probability question.

Your solution is completely correct, and is the fastest way to solve the question.